# Where can I find the limits of the walking parameters of Robotis op 2 in Webots?

Tags: webots

Webots have [walking parameters in config.ini file for Robotis Op 2](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/robotis-op2#walking-parameters).
I want to learn the limits of these parameters like X offset, foot size.
Can you help me?

> **Walking Parameters**
>   This appendix explains all the parameters that can be set in the configuration file (.ini) to tune the gait:

```
Name        Description
X offset    Offset of the feet in the X direction in millimeter.
...
```

Comment: This config file comes originally from the framework of the real robot. It has been roughly copy-pasted in the simulator. In my knowledge, there is no hard-coded limits, but mathematics behind could work weirdly from some point..

Comment: You can find the original documentation of these parameters here: http://support.robotis.com/en/product/darwin-op/development/tools/walking_tuner.htm